# Connect to Cosmos DB emulator

Tags: node.js, mongodb, azure-cosmosdb

When i connect to CosmosDB emulator like this:

```
mongodb://localhost:C2y6yDjf5/R+ob0N8A7Cgv30VRDJIWEHLM+4QDU5DE2nQ9nDuVTqobD4b8mGGyPMbIZnqyMsEcaGQy67XIw/Jw==@localhost:10255/admin?ssl=true
```

everything works as expected but I have

```
promise rejection:
(node:1840) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 2): Error: Password contains an illegal unescaped character
(node:1840) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

How to escape this @ ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

URL-encoding the password part of the connection string may fix this problem. Please try this connection string:

`mongodb://localhost:C2y6yDjf5%2FR%2Bob0N8A7Cgv30VRDJIWEHLM%2B4QDU5DE2nQ9nDuVTqobD4b8mGGyPMbIZnqyMsEcaGQy67XIw%2FJw%3D%3D@localhost:10255/admin?ssl=true`

Does that solve the problem?

Comment: to add to this - some tools handle these pretty well (mongoshell with quotation marks around the conn string) and some don't (Studio 3T for example), so you have to watch out for changes in conn string after you pasted it into the UI.

Comment: yes, thats resolve the problem say this warning
(node:1980) DeprecationWarning: current URL string parser is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new parser, pass option { useNewUrlParser: true } to MongoClient.connect.